# CMake ExternalProjectAdd multiple download URLs

Tags: cmake

Is there a way to specify multiple URLs for ExternalProjectAdd in CMake? So if one is unavailable it will download from another.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can specify multiple URLs to ExternalProject_Add [since CMake v3.7.0](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/commit/2eec433f98f472eb902892ed11b68fae41376ce6):

```
ExternalProject_Add(my_project
    URL http://mirror1/file.tar.gz http://mirror2/file.tar.gz ...
    URL_MD5 ...
    ...)
```